# How to divide value across columns in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: This is the input data]

Above image shows the input, I want to distribute value present in columns to other columns based on the data present in column B.
Lets take an example, in row 1 we have "Quarterly" in column B so the value (120) in 2020_1 column  will be divided by 3 and the value 40(120/3) will be filled in each of(2020_1, 2020_2 , 2002_3). Similarly for row 3 we have 240 in 2020_1 and 90 in 2020_4, so we will divide both by 3 as we have Quarterly in column B and the equal values will be filled in consecutive months. Please refer to the output image for output. Is there any way to do this in Sql. Thanks.
[image: Output]

Comment: You lost me on the semi-annual based on the quarterly logic I would expect semi-annual to have 2 values of 60 for 2020_1 and 2020_2.

Comment: Here the Quarterly means different. Think of it as a payment so we get the payment in 1st month(for 3 months) and we need to distribute it over the months for which we got the payment. For semi-annual we got payment for 6 months in a particular month and we need to distribute it over next 6 months.

Comment: Consider changing your design, enumerated columns are bad and it will get messy if someone decides to make 2 payment in the same period say in months 1 and 2 for row 1.

Comment: What defines the "Start Date" of a payment? In the scenario above, you assume all payments have already started? What happens if a payment starts on 3/2020?

Comment: Think of it as a recharge for 3 months. You can do it in any month but that value should distribute across three months for Quarterly, 6 months for Semi Annual.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this relates to sql. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `Pseudo Code

For each row
If( col B = quarterly)
For each next columns
If (data !=null)
data= data/3
Insert data in the same column and next 2 columns

If( col B = semi annual)
For each next columns
If (data !=null)
data= data/6
Insert data in the same column and next 5 columns`

Comment: Yup we get it but sql isn't good for this at all...

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example you could allocate quarter and semi-annual numbers by date in a cte whilst normalising your data and in the main query find the applicable amount using a correlated sub query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T
(ID INT,B VARCHAR(20),`2020_1` INT,
`2020_2` INT,
`2020_3` INT,
`2020_4` INT,
`2020_5` INT,
`2020_6` INT,
`2020_7` INT,
`2020_8` INT,
`2020_9` INT,
`2020_10` INT,
`2020_11` INT,
`2020_12` INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,'QUARTERLY',120,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(2,'MONTHLY',15,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(3,'SEMI-ANNUAL',120,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(4,'QUARTERLY',120,NULL,NULL,90,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
with cte as
(
select id,b,'202001' mth ,`2020_1` amt ,1 as q, 1 as bi  from t
union all
select id,b,'202002' ,`2020_2` ,1 as qtr, 1 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202003' ,`2020_3` ,1 as qtr, 1 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202004' ,`2020_4` ,2 as qtr, 1 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202005' ,`2020_5` ,2 as qtr, 1 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202006' ,`2020_6` ,2 as qtr, 1 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202007' ,`2020_7` ,3 as qtr, 2 as bi from t
union all
select id,b,'202008' ,`2020_8` ,3 as qtr, 2 as bi  from t
union all
select id,b,'202009' ,`2020_9` ,3 as qtr, 2 as bi  from t
union all
select id,b,'202010' ,`2020_10` ,4 as qtr, 2 as bi  from t
union all
select id,b,'202011' ,`2020_11` ,4 as qtr, 2 as bi  from t
union all
select id,b,'202012' ,`2020_12` ,4 as qtr, 2 as bi  from t
)
select id,b,q,bi,
    case when b = 'quarterly' then
            (select amt from cte c1 where c1.id = cte.id and c1.q = cte.q order by mth limit 1) / 3 
            when b = 'semi-annual' then
            (select amt from cte c1 where c1.id = cte.id and c1.b = cte.b order by mth limit 1) / 6 
          else amt
    end amtsplit
from cte
order by id,mth;

+------+-------------+---+----+----------+
| id   | b           | q | bi | amtsplit |
+------+-------------+---+----+----------+
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    1 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 1 |  1 |  15.0000 |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 1 |  1 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 1 |  1 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 2 |  1 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    2 | MONTHLY     | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 1 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 1 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 1 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 2 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 2 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 2 |  1 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 3 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 3 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 3 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 4 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 4 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    3 | SEMI-ANNUAL | 4 |  2 |  20.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 1 |  1 |  40.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |  30.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |  30.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 2 |  1 |  30.0000 |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 3 |  2 |     NULL |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
|    4 | QUARTERLY   | 4 |  2 |     NULL |
+------+-------------+---+----+----------+
48 rows in set (0.006 sec)
```

Solution will not work if quarters are relative to a start date rather than a calendar date  and it assumes only 1 payment received in quarter. You will have to pivot the results to your format.